# How can I do an if statement on a pandas dataframe to check multiple columns for specific values?

Tags: python, pandas

I am wanting to check a pandas dataframe to see if two columns match two unique values. I know have to check one column at a time, but not two at once.

Basically, I want to see if the person's last name is 'Smith' and their first name is either 'John' or 'Tom' all at the same time.

My code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# create dataframe
name = {'last_name': ['smith','smith','jones','parker'], 'first_name': ['john','tom','mary','peter']}
df = pd.DataFrame(name,columns=['last_name', 'first_name'])

# this is what I want to do
# df.loc[df['last_name'] == 'smith' and df['first_name'].isin(['john', 'tom']), 'match'] = 'yes'

# this works by itself
df.loc[df['last_name'] == 'smith', 'match'] = 'yes'

# this works by itself
df.loc[df['first_name'].isin(['john', 'tom']), 'match'] = 'yes'


print(df)
```

Comment: `df.loc[(df['last_name'] == 'smith') & (df['first_name'].isin(['john', 'tom'])), 'match'] = 'yes'` You need to use the bitwise and operator - i.e., `&`.

Comment: Another way: `df['match'] = np.where((df['last_name'] == 'smith') & (df['first_name'].isin(['john', 'tom'])), 'yes', 'no')`

Comment: Okay, yeah it looks like me not using `&` and enough parentheses is where I went wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to filter rows where the last name is "Smith" AND the first name is either "John" OR "Tom". This means it's either "John Smith" OR "Tom Smith". This is equivalent to

```
(last_name=="Smith" AND first_name=="John") OR (last_name=="Smith" AND first_name=="Tom")
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(last_name=="smith") AND (first_name=='john' OR first_name=='tom')
```

the latter OR can be handled using `isin`:

```
out = df[(df['last_name']=='smith') & (df['first_name'].isin(['john','tom']))]
```

Output:

```
  last_name first_name match
0     smith       john   yes
1     smith        tom   yes
```

Comment: This did the trick! I think I just didn't have enough parentheses in mine! Also not using `&` instead of `and`. Thanks!

Comment: In addition to this, is it possible to do this as an actual if statement or is this the best way to handle this?



`if df.loc[(df['last_name'] == 'smith') & (df['first_name'].isin(['john', 'tom']))]:` vs `if df["match"].isin(["yes"]).any():`

Comment: @Cole if you're filtering rows, using boolean indexing is the best way; but you can write an if condition like: `(x['last_name']=='smith') & (x['first_name'] in ['john','tom'])`. In this case you're evaluating row by row

Comment: Basically, I am wanting to check if any rows exist where first_name = `john` OR `tom` AND last_name = `smith`. And if there are rows then execute this other code, if not continue on as normal. And I will have multiple checks like that looking for specific last_name and first_name combinations. I am not sure on the most efficient way to do this though.

Comment: @Cole sounds like you could write all of these conditions in a list and use `np.select`

Comment: do you have an example or a link to some documentation to help me get going with that?

Comment: @Cole take a look at [`np.select` official docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). I'm sure there are many tutorials on how to use it, if you google "how to use numpy select". Maybe there are answers on this very website too. But first take a look at the docs and see if it suits to your needs. You can always create a question here.